# EditText set background opacity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-background

I have some troubles to make an `EditText` transparent. This is what I want : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fgXt.png)

I tried :

- Apply background to editText with custom shape :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
      <solid android:color="@color/transparentButton"/> 
    <!-- this one is  this color of the Rounded Button -->
    <corners
      android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topRightRadius="0dp"/>
  </shape>`

  <color name="transparentButton"> #4CFFFFFF </color>

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/usernameLoginTxt"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_username_login"
      android:drawablePadding="15dp"
      android:background="@drawable/editetextbackground"
      android:ems="10"
      android:inputType="textPersonName"
      android:hint="Username"
      android:textColorHint="@color/black"
      android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
      app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/titreLogin"
      android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
      app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/titreLogin"
      android:layout_marginTop="44dp"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/soustitrelogin"/>
  ```

But with this method the size is reduced as you can see : 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7Ken.png)

- I tried setalpha too but all is transparent, editText, icon and text

Thanks for your help, i hope that you will understand me.

Comment: try android:background="@null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this add `android:padding="10dp"` to your `EditText` like this

```
 <EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:hint="Nilesh Rathod"
    android:drawablePadding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cart" />
```

**drawable/edittext** file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="#c0d7d0d0" /> <!-- this one is ths color of the Rounded Button -->

</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you it works!  I thought I had put it but it was just in the shape, so i accepted your answer !